# Mapping multiple URL into Servlet Controller using annotation

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am novice in servlet development and I want to map these URL patterns to my BookController Servlet:

1. mysite.com/Books/Add
2. mysite.com/Books/Delete/1

How they can be mapped using Annotation or web.xml and can I process both of them inside doGet() method?

```
public class BookController extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException {
  }

}
```